# Show most recent result only from GROUP BY

Tags: php, sql

I need to show only the most recent entries in the results I know I should do a join or inner join but cannot seem to get that to work properly. I am sure it is something simple I am over looking.

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM form_2 GROUP BY jobname");
```

I am looking to get only the most resent result by jobname.

Right Now it displays the first entries with the same jobname I need the most recent.
When someone added a comment the jobname is the consistent. And I need to just display the most recent entire to show the most recent comment added with that jobname.

Comment: There's nothing wrong. You'll get the most recent (by awardedcon) entries. If you one want *the* most recent *one* use `LIMIT 1`.

Comment: The jobnames are the duplicate's, they need to be joined and sorted by the most recent jobname.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
select form_2.*
from form_2
inner join (
    select jobname, max(awardedcon) as max_value
    from form_2
    group by jobname
) as a on form_2.jobname=a.jobname and form_2.awardedcon=a.max_value
```

I am assuming that `awardedcon` is an increasing value for each `jobname` (*i.e.* the most recent entry for each `jobname` will have the biggest `awardedcon` value)

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Yes its getting me closer, I just removed the awardedcon value for this because its not really relevant to get what I need working, I need to get the most recent entire by jobname not awardedcon.

Comment: Do you have a date or some value you can use to sort the `jobname` entries (the record Id, for example)?

Comment: I have a timestamp saved with each?

Comment: (assuming that `ts` is the name of the field with the timestamp) you can try `max(ts) as max_value` in the subquery, and `form_2.ts=a.max_value`

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT jobname,
       max(awardedcon) as last_awardedcon
FROM form_2 
GROUP BY jobname
ORDER BY last_awardedcon DESC
```